# EF core ToAsyncEnumerable and AsAsyncEnumerable ends with System.ObjectDisposedException

Tags: c#, asynchronous, entity-framework-core, repository-pattern, iasyncenumerable

I'm working on xamarin project and using Entity Framework Core to access database. I know it's not a good solution but i decided to do it without application server.

The DAL layer is using repository pattern and BL layer is using facade pattern with mappers.
On the DAL layer i want to create IAsyncEnumerable of entities and on BL i want to make IAsyncEnumerable of models.

The first and the second example does not work, It ends on System.ObjectDisposedException "Cannot access a disposed context instance..." Why? ToList() works good, ToListAsync() works good.

**Ends on System.ObjectDisposedException**

```
public IAsyncEnumerable<TaskEntity> GetTasksByTaskGroupIdAndKanbanStateAsync(Guid taskGroupId, string kanbanStateName, CancellationToken token)
        {
            using (WorkManagerDbContext dbContext = IdbContextFactory.CreateDbContext())
            {
                return dbContext.TaskSet.AsQueryable().Where(s => s.TaskGroup.Id == taskGroupId)
    .Where(s => s.State.Name == kanbanStateName).ToAsyncEnumerable();
            }
        }
```

**Ends on System.ObjectDisposedException**

```
public IAsyncEnumerable<TaskEntity> GetTasksByTaskGroupIdAndKanbanStateAsync(Guid taskGroupId, string kanbanStateName, CancellationToken token)
        {
            using (WorkManagerDbContext dbContext = IdbContextFactory.CreateDbContext())
            {
                return dbContext.TaskSet.AsQueryable().Where(s => s.TaskGroup.Id == taskGroupId).
    Where(s => s.State.Name == kanbanStateName).AsAsyncEnumerable();
            }
        }
```

**Working** solution but i don't know if it's good solution.

```
public IAsyncEnumerable<TaskEntity> GetTasksByTaskGroupIdAndKanbanStateAsync(Guid taskGroupId, string kanbanStateName, CancellationToken token)
        {
            using (WorkManagerDbContext dbContext = IdbContextFactory.CreateDbContext())
            {
                return dbContext.TaskSet.AsQueryable().Where(s => s.TaskGroup.Id == taskGroupId)
                    .Where(s => s.State.Name == kanbanStateName).ToList().ToAsyncEnumerable();
            }
        }
```

Comment: You're constructing them inside a `using` clause and then returning them out of it, which disposes of the context object before the collections are actually hydrated.

Comment: Make WorkManagerDbContext scoped inside your container and then remove the using statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this happening because the .ToAsyncEnumerable() will execute the db call when you are using the object (lazy loaded). ToList() will execute the db call immediately. So when you are using this inside a using statement, the DbContext is disposed while the return object is returned. the .ToList() is the right solution in this situation.

How ever, I am having doubts about your approach of creating and disposing of DbContext because it might leads to other problems later (like updating a object which is being tracked in another context instance etc). Also you will lose some benefits like, caching of results.